# Why is LVM metadata backed up to /etc/lvm and not /boot?

Tags: linux, lvm

Recent question I saw got me thinking on this particular point:

- If bootloader restrictions usually cause `/boot` to be outside LVM, why isn't this the target of LVM metadata backups?

Putting it underneath `/etc` seems like it would make a chicken and egg dilemma possible if we're restoring a PV for the root filesystem's VG versus just having it already available for access in rescue mode.

Also, if most installers make the root filesystem LVM, it would seem they're almost intentionally creating the situation (versus the distro doing a symlink from `/etc/lvm/archive` to a directory underneath `/boot` or patching the tools to look for LVM information in `/boot`).

Not that it's really a problem (I can usually just get it out of backup) but it would seem like having it under `/boot` is more ideal. I was wondering what the logic might have been for locating it under `/etc`.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it be in `/boot`? None of these files are required for booting. `/boot` does not sound like a good choice as on many systems, it's not mounted or mounted read-only, if they even have a separate `/boot` partition at all which many do not, what with GRUB2 supporting all sorts of things.

At the same time the files are useful for undoing accidents within the running system, so they should be somewhere readily accessible in the standard tree. Whether that's `/etc` or `/var` or whatever.

As for the chicken and egg dilemma, you should have backups anyway.

If you are in a situation where you need those files, you can find them in the raw data thanks to their distinctive and informative header.

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.99(2) (2013-07-24): Wed Aug 28 08:54:15 2013
```

Fragmentation could still be an issue but the files are usually small enough to be unfragmented, and even in the fragmentation case you might be able to locate the correct fragment by checking the file syntax.

You have a very good chance of recovery. Of course, making backups is so much simpler.

If you absolutely want to move the files elsewhere, you can always use a symlink, or set `LVM_SYSTEM_DIR`.

Comment: "None of these files are required for booting" If a PV for the root filesystem is corrupt, it very well could be required for booting insofar as it restores your ability to do so successfully. It also doesn't seem like mounting `/boot` read-only or not mounting it at all is a good idea since theoretically you're going to do kernel updates or want to reconfigure the bootloader. I don't really see the benefit of not mounting a filesystem that small and just using unix permissions to secure it.

Comment: I'm also not currently planning on relocating this or doing any symlinks, I was just curious as to what the logic was. I may or may not do that in the future, I just felt like I needed to know the answer to this question.

Comment: The data is also stored in the header of each PV. So if you have more than one, it's redundant.

Comment: The use case here is when those PV's become corrupted, of which, there may be only one. I could understand that this wouldn't be so much of an issue/concern if the default was to have two copies of metadata per PV but the default is just one.

Answer (score 1):

LVM has no business looking at `/boot`.  That partition doesn't even have to be mounted outside of kernel updates.  `/var/backup` is the more logical location however, and I expect LVM will move to it as part of making `/etc` read-only.

(responding to comments)
Control over the kernel is sufficiently important that sysadmins don't keep `/boot` mounted permanently, and virtualised environments often hide it from the OS entirely.

Even if you could assume that `/boot` is available, is outside of LVM, and you've come up with a scenario where that filesystem would survive whatever event damages the metadata areas, your suggestion would still be a terribly ad-hoc way to do disaster recovery. Defaulting to two metadata areas per PV probably wouldn't hurt (Gentoo did it and ironed out the bugs), but special-casing LVM backups to go to an unusual location which, unlike `/etc` and most of `/var`, is unlikely to be copied off-site would.

Comment: OK, but your "have to" is based on current practice which is what I'm asking about. Is there some problem with keeping `/boot` mounted? As far as FHS goes, the point I'm trying to make is that LVM meta data (being used for the root filesystem in default RHEL/CentOS installs) is required for booting. The backups are mostly only useful to have when physical volumes have become corrupted so it doesn't make sense to require LVM operation in order to restore LVM operation. That's like purposefully locking your keys in your car.

Comment: This is something you can set up on your own if you like, but it will never be something that will be done without asking you. Simply because it won't work everywhere. Besides the PV corruption case is far fetched as is, everything else (filesystems, mdadm, cryptsetup/LUKS) would suffer fatally from such a thing as well.

Comment: @frostchutz OK but we're back at the "have to" part of Tobu's logic. People who aren't mounting `/boot` or are mounting it read-only are only doing so because it doesn't cause any problems. So is there really a concrete benefit to an unwritable `/boot`? If not, it seems like the chicken and egg problem is much more likely to be result than non-existent problems with mounting `/boot`. I've ran into LVM corruption, but I have yet to encounter a problem that made me wish `/boot` wasn't writable. If there's no use case for an unmounted `/boot` I don't think this would factor into LVM design.