# can you recover lvm metadata without access to /etc/lvm/?

Tags: lvm, data-recovery

I just installed Manjaro on to a externalized usb hard drive. After I was done, I tried to boot from my previously working **Mint** distro (no full-disk luks) on my internal hard drive. The lvm volume groups had disappeared!?

```
    [crow ~]$ sudo lvm vgscan
    [sudo] password for crow:
      Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
      Found volume group "ManjaroVG" using metadata type lvm2
    [crow ~]$ sudo pvscan
      PV /dev/mapper/cryptManjaro   VG ManjaroVG   lvm2 [465.51 GiB / 0    free]
      Total: 1 [465.51 GiB] / in use: 1 [465.51 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
    [crow ~]$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

    Disk /dev/sdb: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disklabel type: dos
    Disk identifier: 0x00079473

    Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
    /dev/sdb1  *      2048    499711    497664   243M 83 Linux
    /dev/sdb2       501758 976771071 976269314 465.5G  5 Extended
    /dev/sdb5       501760 976771071 976269312 465.5G 8e Linux LVM

    [crow ~]$ sudo pvs
    [sudo] password for crow:
      PV                       VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
      /dev/mapper/cryptManjaro ManjaroVG lvm2 a--  465.51g    0
    [crow ~]$ sudo pvdisplay
      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/mapper/cryptManjaro
      VG Name               ManjaroVG
      PV Size               465.51 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes (but full)
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              119170
      Free PE               0
      Allocated PE          119170
      PV UUID               B8f73k-Najv-6hVM-XxHm-Wk9F-zeZ9-69MsxN

    [crow ~]$ sudo pvdisplay /dev/sdb5
      Failed to find physical volume "/dev/sdb5"

     [crow ~]$ sudo file -s /dev/sdb5
     /dev/sdb5: data
```

I have switched the disks around and now the non-working disk is `/dev/sdb`.
I have read that there is meta data backup in `/etc/lvm` which is of course inside `/dev/sdb5` and not `/boot` at `/dev/sdb1`.
I would like to see a better answer for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92171/why-is-lvm-metadata-backed-up-to-etc-lvm-and-not-boot).

---

If there is not a way to restore the disks then what are my options?  Are these among them?

- Are there any forensics tools that can give access to the data?
- Another thing is the partition scheme was the standard linux Mint. If
  I reinstalled Mint could the new meta-data be used to try to recover
  the old?

Comment: What do you get from `sudo pvs` and `pvdisplay /dev/sdb5`?

Comment: You missed the argument to pvdisplay. `sudo pvdisplay /dev/sdb5`. I presume /dev/sdb is where the Mint install you're trying to recover lives? If not, which disk does it live on?

Comment: Yes, it should be on /dev/sd5. command finds nothing.

Comment: Maybe they set up some LVM filter... Does `grep -P '^\s*filter' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf` give anything?

Comment: the readable /etc/lvm is now Manjaro aka Archlinux on /dev/sda, so I dont see what the use is. But anyways grep does not find anything.

Comment: The config in /etc/lvm is what the LVM tools are using to decide if they're allowed to look at that PV. I guess next would be to add a few `-v`'s to that pvdisplay, and look through that output to see what it's saying about `/dev/sdb5`. I suspect your data (and prior LVM setup) is perfectly fine, you just have some LVM config that is telling the machine not to read it.

Comment: The drive is setup to boot, where it failed to find the mint volumes. My opinion is when Manjaro installed it wiped all the volume groups system wide instead of just the drive I asked it install on (As that was the point Mint stopped working.)

Comment: What about `file -s /dev/sdb5`? Does that say its an LVM2 PV? If so, it probably didn't wipe them.

Comment: It says `data`. Uh Oh. See code listing above.

Comment: sanity check, what does `file -s /dev/mapper/cryptManjaro` show? Just to make sure your `file` recognizes LVM PVs.

Comment: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: B8f73k-Najv-6hVM-XxHm-Wk9F-zeZ9-69MsxN, size: 499837304832

Comment: :-( ... Ok, that sounds like it did wipe the LVM data off the disk. Any chance you have a backup of `/etc/lvm` from Mint somewhere? Otherwise, maybe you're lucky and it was lazy, and the config is still there. `sudo strings /dev/sdb5 | less` might give an LVM config. Should start out with your VG name and a open brace (`{`). Actually, strings will find the backup out of /etc as well, but that will be much further in. (note: be careful pasting anything from that strings output, it will contain your data! Which you probably want to keep confidential)

Comment: Its there! you are awesome!

Comment: OK. Note that there will be a bunch of them. LVM keeps old ones, they should have date stamps so you can find the newest. You should be able to feed that to `vgcfgrestore`. Personally, I'd make an image of `/dev/sdb5` first, just in case. (Note: I've never actually done that restore before myself; https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html has some docs which suggest you may need a `pvcreate` with appropriate options as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the header did get cleared off your physical volumes. Thankfully, LVM stores a fairly large header, including multiple backups of the metadata, in plain text.

So you can find the plain-text metadata using, e.g., `sudo strings /dev/sdb5 | less` and use that metadata to restore the physical volume. Note that there will possibly be multiple copies from different dates; make sure to use the most-recent (there is a date stamp in them). Once you've used `strings` (and some hand-editing of its output, possibly) to get a config backup, you can use the steps in the [CentOS LVM recovery documentation](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html) to restore access to the volume group.

I strongly recommend making an image of the partition before attempting recovery.

Comment: I was able to recover the partition. Thx. One thing though: strings did not capture the closing `}` brackets. I used `cat /dev/sdxx > data` then used vim to find the correct file. Then I had to fsck the partition and hold down the y for a minute or two. But it worked.

Comment: @user17130 odd about that fsck. Anyway, keep that image that you hopefully took around for a bit, just in case. Also may want to check what you used to recover vs. what's in /etc to be sure.

Comment: I don't understand how you did, what have you done after `cat /dev/sdxx > data`? What did you edit/remove from this data file? All parts that concern old config contents or You kept just the last config content version or all other data too? And also, you chose this file for the `--restorefile` options of the `pvcreate` command? And what about `vgcfgrestore`?

Comment: @temp_user_4_commenting maybe you should ask your own question, since `cat` isn't anywhere in my answer AFAIK.