# Recoving LVM logical volumes after having to recreate the physical volumes

Tags: data-recovery, lvm

After reinstalling my system to a new SSD, my existing LVM was toast, it couldn’t find any physical volumes or volume groups.

I also don’t have backups of my LVM configuration.

Also to further complicate matters the LVM is spread across two Raid one devices.

Now I have a new volume group with the two raid devices as physical devices in it.

They claim to be empty and have no logical volumes.

```
[ben@manjaro ~]$ sudo !!
sudo pvscan 
PV /dev/md127   VG new   lvm2 [1.82 TiB / 1.82 TiB free]
PV /dev/md125   VG new   lvm2 [931.27 GiB / 931.27 GiB free]
Total: 2 [2.73 TiB] / in use: 2 [2.73 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

However I am convinced the data is still present on the partitions, I am running testdisk, which appears to be finding EXT4 file systems.

Ideally I would like to be able to recover the data of the disks, I am not too bothered by having the LVM back as I can recreate that from scratch if necessary.

Comment: does this [previous question and answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154630/can-you-recover-lvm-metadata-without-access-to-etc-lvm) help?

Comment: I have run the command mentioned there, but I am not sure what I am looking for to restore the data, for the logical volumes