# LVM Metadata recover without access to /et/lvm (sic)

Tags: lvm, data-recovery

I've made a mistake with my luks lvm device. Yesterday I wanted to extend my vg-home logical volume with a second disk, so I did `vgextend /dev/sdb1 vg` (vg is the name of my volume group) but when I did `df -h`, the size of my vg-home volume was still the same.

So I played around with several solutions, I have remove the disk from the group, unplug the disk ans plug it again but I had the unknown device problem (unknow device in my vg group). So I did `vgreduce --removemissing`, hoping it will work, but it removed the entire vg-home volume !

So now, I have no access to my physical volume. I have to boot to debian live USB, and after doing `cryptsetupp luksOpen /dev/sda1 vg`, `pvscan` with or without `--cache` option just returns `Reading volume groups from cache`, `vgchange -ay` returns nothing as `pvs`, `lvs` and `vgs`. `lsblk` shows

```
sda      8:0    0 298,1G  0 disk  
 └─sda1   8:1    0 298,1G  0 part  
    └─vg 254:0    0 298,1G  0 crypt
```

`fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/mapper/vg: 298,1 GiB, 320069787648 bytes, 625136304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device               Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/vg-part1 *        2048  16779263  16777216     8G 82 Linux swap / So
/dev/mapper/vg-part2      16779264  69208063  52428800    25G 83 Linux
/dev/mapper/vg-part3      69208064 625133567 555925504 265,1G 83 Linux
```

TestDisk says it doesn't support the filesystem when I try to list the file of my home and root volume (it recognize it). So I thought my last solution was on this post : [can you recover lvm metadata without access to /etc/lvm/?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154630/can-you-recover-lvm-metadata-without-access-to-etc-lvm/154678?noredirect=1#comment824936_154678)

I did `strings /dev/sda1 > data` but I don't understand what I have to do after that. What I have to edit/remove from this data file ? All parts that concern old config contents or just keep the last version of config content ?  With or without all other data too ? And also is this file I have to indicate for `--restorefile` options of the `pvcreate` command ? And what about `vgcfgrestore` ?